# Scrapy JSON output - values empty

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I would like to crawl a set of web pages using scrapy.  However, when I try to write some values into the json file, those fields don't show up.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class LLPubs (scrapy.Spider):
    name = "linlinks"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.linnaeuslink.org/records/record/1',
        'http://www.linnaeuslink.org/records/record/2',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for container in response.css('div.item'):
            yield {
                'text': container.css('div.field.soulsbyNo .value span::text').extract(),
                'uniformtitle': container.css('div.field.uniformTitle .value span::text').extract(),
                'title': container.css('div.field.title .value span::text').extract(),
                'opac': container.css('div.field.localControlNo .value span::text').extract(),
                'url': container.css('div#digitalLinks li a').extract(),
                'partner': container.css('div.logoContainer  img:first-child').xpath('@src').extract(),
                }
```

And an example of my output:

```
{
"text": ["Soulsby no. 46(1)"], 
"uniformtitle": ["Systema naturae"], 
"title": ["Caroli Linn\u00e6i ... Systema natur\u00e6\nin quo natur\u00e6 regna tria, secundum classes, ordines, genera, species, systematice proponuntur."], 
"opac": ["002178079"], 
"url": [], 
"partner": []
},
```

I am hoping I am doing something silly and easy to fix!  Both of the paths I am using for "url" and "partner" were working from here:

```
scrapy shell 'http://www.linnaeuslink.org/records/record/1'
```

So, I just don't know what I am missing.

Oh, and exporting to json by using this command for now:

```
scrapy crawl linlinks -o quotes.json
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that those selectors are not "findable" inside any `div.item` you probably have validated them without the `response.css('div.item')` to replicate what you used in the shell just replace the `container.css` by `response.css` for the `url` and `partner` keys.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much.  I was trying to figure out how to target it and it makes sense that I have to use a higher level selector... or what have you.